# Scrolling Panel Printing Issue

Tags: asp.net, css, printing, panel

I have a site where we have the content in scrolling panels to make it neater and line up. The issue comes when trying to print the contents of my panel hidden by the scroll.

Here is my panel

```
<asp:Panel Height="400px" ID="pnlContent" class="ContentPanel ScrollBars="Vertical" runat="server" > 
<!-- Content bla bla bla -->
</asp:Panel>
```

Here is my media="print" style sheet code for the ContentPanel

```
.ContentScroller  
{
    overflow:visible;
}
```

The overflow:visible does not seem to remover the ScrollBars="Vertical"

Any ideas on how to get this hidden content to print?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a print specific media query to change the overflow like this:

```
@media print
{
 .ContentScroller  
 {
     overflow:auto;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height to 100%.

```
height: 100%;
```

This may be a problem with your

```
Height="400px"
```

set in your server tag. I create 2 CSS files, 1 for screen and 1 for print then remove sizing from the server tags.